# The proper way to save a form in POST Edit?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-4

I'm sorta new to asp .net and mvc in general. I'm implementing the GET edit and POST edit methods of a controller. I'm using a strongly-typed view to edit a form. I'm passing the model back to the POST edit method, but I don't know how to save it. Here's what I have so far... It's not much I know.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ModifyContract(ModContract mod)
    {
        // submit modified contract
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            OutlookMediaEntities1 db = new OutlookMediaEntities1();
            db.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(mod, EntityState.Modified);

            // save changes
            db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("ContractDetails", "Contract", new { id = (int) ViewData["contractid"] });
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Missing necessary information");
            return View();
        }
    }
```

I'm getting a InvalidOperationException on the db.ObjectStateManager... line. I saw something that said it might be because I didn't assign a primary key and noticed my ModAds class (below) didn't include a primary key. Added it but I get the same error. Here's the stack trace:

```
[InvalidOperationException: The ObjectStateManager does not contain an ObjectStateEntry with a reference to an object of type 'oulookmediaweb.Models.ModContract'.]
   System.Data.Objects.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(Object entity, EntityState entityState) +278
   oulookmediaweb.Controllers.ContractController.ModifyContract(ModContract mod) in C:\Users\georgiev.1\Outlook4\oulookmediaweb\Controllers\ContractController.cs:1113
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +163
   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +17
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +205
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.c__DisplayClass42.b__41() +28
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.c__DisplayClass8`1.b__7(IAsyncResult _) +12
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +57
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.c__DisplayClass39.b__33() +58
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.c__DisplayClass4f.b__49() +237
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.c__DisplayClass37.b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +12
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +57
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.c__DisplayClass2a.b__20() +24
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.c__DisplayClass25.b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +126
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +57
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +45
   System.Web.Mvc.c__DisplayClass1d.b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +14
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.c__DisplayClass4.b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +25
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +61
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.c__DisplayClass4.b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +25
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.c__DisplayClass8.b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.c__DisplayClass4.b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +25
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +49
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +8970141
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +184
```

Here's the model as well:

```
public class ModContract
{
    public int contract_id;
    public string contract_name { get; set; }
    public List<ModAds> ads;

    public string print_product_id { get; set; }
    public string print_ad_option_id { get; set; }
}

public class ModAds
{
    public int contr_ad_id;
    public string name;
    public string product_name;
    public string adv_product;
    public List<string> editions;
    public double freq_disc;
    public double other_dis_dol;
    public double? other_dis_per;
    public string non_cash_note;
    public double non_cash_cons;
}
```

I have no idea how to save the model that's passed. All the tutorials I've looked at have really simple models and the saving is done with something like,

```
db.Entry(model).State = EntityState.Modified;
db.SaveChanges();
```

The first line doesn't even compile when I put it in my code; it says there's no method Entry. How does the model get the new values from the form fields? How does the view know to pass that model as a parameter? Is it because the view is strongly-typed? What happens if it's not? Does the view round up all the input and select stuff in a form element and put them in the model? I'm just confused about how it all works. And most importantly, how do I save the model?

Any help or links to help is appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you say "model" I assume those are entities that you query from your database and pass on to the view?

Comment: Yes, I'm querying the database in the GET edit and putting the queried stuff in a model and returning View(model).

Comment: Are you using EF 4.1 and above?

Comment: No it's 4.0 I believe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The first line doesn't even compile when I put it in my code; it says
>   there's no method Entry.

This is most probably because you are using an old version of EF. Prior to 4.1 EF uses the `ObjectContext` that does not have an `Entry` method. EF 4.1+ uses the DbContext that has the `Entry` method. Also, you have a parameter named `mod` and you are saving a variable named `model`, is that a typo error? There is [a great tutorial on EF and MVC here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application).

> How does the model get the new values from the form fields? How does the view know to pass that model as a parameter?

It's called [model binding that is greatly explains here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh781022.aspx).

> Is it because the view is strongly-typed?

Yes

> What happens if it's not?

You can still take advantage of the model binding as long as you name your HTML element properly. For example, you have a controller method declared as:

```
[HttpPost]
ActionResult Product(int id, string name) {
}
```

The model binder can do it's job if you name your elements matching the parameter names:

```
<input type="hidden" name="id"/>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name"/>
```

> Does the view round up all the input and select stuff in a form
>   element and put them in the model?

See model binding.

> And most importantly, how do I save the model?

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ModifyContract(ModContract mod)
{
    // do some validation or anything else you need to do here
    // then save your entity
    db.Entry(mod).State = EntityState.Modified;
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Are you sure about "EF 4.1+ uses the DbContext"?  I thought that Code first used DbContext and model first used ObjectContext, regardless of EF version.  I might be wrong though.  Although you can use a DbContext generator template to generate a DbContext from model first.  My guess is the asker is using Model First, but have some code from an MVC example that used Code First.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks! I am using EF 4.0 though, so the db.Entry thing doesn't work. The db.Entry line wasn't part of my code (I removed it cause it didn't work), I just wanted to illustrate what I've seen in tutorials, like the one you linked to lol. Any links to tutorials for EF 4.0?

Comment: For a moment there I was not sure, so I dig into some old projects using EF and double checked if it was referencing version `4.1.10715.0`, to make sure I'm not misleading anyone. So yes DbContext is available in that version. And thanks for the remark @AaronLS :)

Comment: You're welcome @maus. If you are still starting out on your project I suggest you use the latest version, version 5 I think. It may have a few issues but it will outweigh it with the benefits it bring plus resolved issues from the previous version.

Comment: Actually @vonv. it's a group project and it's been worked on for a while. Would rather not update anything at this point.

Comment: I see. Well, I don't have any bookmark for EF 4.0 tutorial, sorry can't help there. But for the saving part you can do something like this: `db.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(your_entity, EntityState.Modified);`.

Comment: Didn't work... Getting a InvalidOperationException. Maybe something's wrong with how I'm declaring the model stuff.

Comment: Please post the entire stack trace in your original question.

Comment: Do an `Attach` first: `db.Attach(your_entity)` and if it still doesn't work, post another question. SO is complaining already about our long conversation here and you don't have enough reputation to start a chat.

Comment: Ugh I know. Thanks @vonv. if you could check out my new question that would be great.